# what's the best way to store stream of data over tcp into large array?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, tcpsocket

i wanna to store the stream of data over TCP connection into large array, how can i do that?

my code:

```
int iResult, count;
int recvbuflen = 512;
char buff[4096]={0};
char recvbuf[512] = {0};

.................

count = 0;

do {

    iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if (iResult > 0) {

                count+=iResult;

                //code to store in the buff[] array until reach to 4096 byte
                //that's what i need
                //for example: each time bind or add the recvbuf[] array at 
                //the end of buff[] array until reach to 4096 byte. 

                if(count == 4096)
                {
                  //do the next process
                  count = 0; 
                }
              }
    }while(iResult > 0);
```

any helping.

Comment: You have the right principle, but you should receive `iResult` bytes *less*  in the next iteration of the loop. Otherwise you may receive `4095` bytes in the first call (first iteration) and `4096` in the next call (next iteration), which is not what you want.

Comment: no i know that's the received data not exceed the 4096 byte.

Comment: @abdo.eng2006210: no, you will be receiving at most 512 bytes each time, so be prepared to copy the number of bytes that you have received after the already received bytes.  And normally, you should also check that you could receive more than 4096 bytes in total.

Comment: my be receive stream each time with 512 bytes or less so i need to collect each 8 from the received data and storing them in the large buff[4096] array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just directly recv into your big buffer and add an offset every time:

```
iRes = recv(ClientSocket, (buff+offset), 4096-offset, 0);
```

Etc. Just watch out not to overflow the buffer. If you need to receive the data separately and add them to the buffer depending on content, just memcpy the recvbuf into buffer (with offset). The offset just keeps track up until which point the buffer is already filled. 
Again, keep an eye out for buffer overflows.